# resposta em `jSon` recebido de um arquivo `php`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte resposta em `jSon` recebido de um arquivo `php`.

```
{"1":"OK","2":"n"}
```

Quero agora, em `jQuery` pegar os **valores** dos **índices** `1` e `2` que são respectivamente `"OK"` e `"n"`.

Como fazer isso?

Meu bloco está assim:

```
  $("a#bloqDesbloq").click(function() {

     $.post ("../_requeridos/alteraAdministrador.php", {

         idAdministrador   : $(this).attr('idAdmin'),
         bloq      :         $(this).attr('bloq')

     }, function(retorno){
                     alert(retorno[1]);
          if (retorno[1] == "OK") {
              if (retorno[2] == "s")  $("a#bloqDesbloq img").prop("src",'_img/desbloquear.png')
              if (retorno[2] == "n")  $("a#bloqDesbloq img").prop("src",'_img/bloquear.png')
              location.reload();
          } else {
            alert("Erro no bloqueio");
            location.reload();
          }

       }
      );
        return false;

  });
```

Fazendo:

```
alert(retorno[1]);
```

Só dá como retorno aspas duplas

```
"
```

Comment: Utilize o `JSON.parse()` ou defina corretamente o parâmetro [`dataType`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: Ok retorno = JSON.parse(_retorno);

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
  $("a#bloqDesbloq").on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../_requeridos/alteraAdministrador.
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data) // aqui vai estar o retorno da sua requisição!
                          // A partir daqui é só vc trata-lo para exibir da forma que quiser..

    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);  // Caso aconteça algum erro ele ira exibir no console!
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que definir o tipo de retorno. O exemplo seria o `dataType: json`

```
    $('#bloqDesbloq').on('click', function(){
       var idAdmin = $(this).attr('idAdmin');
       var bloq    = $(this).attr('bloq');
       $.ajax({
         url : '../_requeridos/alteraAdministrador.php',
         type : 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
           idAdministrador : idAdmin,
           bloq : bloq
          }
       }).
        done( function( data ){
        if( data.1 == "OK" ){
          if ( data.2  == "s")  
              $("#bloqDesbloq").prop("src",'_img/desbloquear.png')
          if (data.2 == "n") 
               $("#bloqDesbloq").prop("src",'_img/bloquear.png')
       }else{

       }
    })
 })
```

Outra opção é usar o

```
$.post('script.php', data, function(response) {
    // Do something with the request
}, 'json');
```

Fonte: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/postjson-for-jquery

Comment: e como defino retorno tipo usando $.post ao invés de $.ajax?

Comment: Tentou com  JSON.parse( retorno )

Comment: sim, deu certo!

Comment: Segue essa diga [dica](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/postjson-for-jquery)